# Definition of degree

Tags: algebraic-topology

By Hatcher P134, degree is defined from a map $f: S^n \to S^n$ - but degree must be able to applied to all maps. Can I arbitrarily generalize the definition of degree to a map between any two spaces?

> For a map $f: S^n \to S^n$ with $n > 0$, the induced map $f_*: H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$ is an homomorphism from an infinite cyclic group to itself and so must be of the form $f_*(\alpha) = d \alpha$ for some integer $d$ depending only on $f$. This integer is called the **degree** of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common generalization of this notion of degree is for a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are closed connected orientable manifolds of the same dimension $n$. These conditions imply that the top homology groups $H_n(X)$ and $H_n(Y)$ are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. In order to define the degree we must fix an orientation of each of $X$ and $Y$; this amounts to choosing generators $[X]$ and $[Y]$ of $H_n(X)$ and $H_n(Y)$ respectively. Then the map $f$ induces on homology is defined in terms of these generators by
$$f_*([X]) = d[Y]$$ for some $d\in\mathbb{Z}$, which is by definition the degree of $f$. Note that choosing a different orientation for either $X$ or $Y$ would change the degree of $f$ by a sign.

Comment: That is very helpful, and very clear. Thank you a lot Brad.